# NumericUpDown to set decimal points?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a NumericUpDown box set the decimal points of a textbox and update everytime it is clicked up or down. I have tried it 2 different ways:

```
Me.txtCalc.Text = FormatNumber(Me.txtCalc.Text, Me.NumericUpDown1.Value)
```

This way works but it isn't keeping the decimal values when i increase the value. So if the textbox said 2 and is really supposed to be 2.987899. I change the NumericUpDown box from 0 to 6 and all it does is display: 2.000000.

I've also tried it this way (Which i think I'm doing wrong..)

```
Me.txtCalc.Text = Math.Round(CDec(Me.txtCalc.Text), CInt(Me.NumericUpDown1.Value))
```

This was the only way I could get it to do anything. And when I try this, everytime I click the vlaue to go up, it does absolutely nothing. But if I set it to 7 first **and then** add some values like: 2.987899; when i click from 7 down to 1, it removes one point at a time like it should... it just doesnt go back up. at all.

I assume I **have** to use Math.Round because that's the only way it will **keep** the decimal values...

Hopefully I explained this so you guys understand.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not just use the NumericUpDown to set/get the value and skip the TB - Min, Max, Value and Increment are all Decimal type

Comment: I don't know what you mean..

Comment: ok, well when you go from 7 down to 1, you are not just formatting a value to X places, you are changing the value.  When it gets to 0, the  text is `2`  and the value is 2.  It cant also be 2.987899 or anything else unless you store the VALUE in a variable and format/tostring that in the text box.  It CANT 'go back up' because the value changed: `Me.txtCalc.Text = FormatNumber...` changes the value for the next go around...  The NUD could edit a decimal value if that is what you are ultimately after.

Comment: Right. But when I use Math.Round, it keeps the decimal places. The problem is, the code doesn't make the decimal values increase by the value of the NumericUpDown, it only decreases by that value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Me.txtCalc.Text = FormatNumber(Me.txtCalc.Text, Me.NumericUpDown1.Value)
```

this not only formats the value, it resets the starting value for any next iteration.  Assuming a start of 2.987899 going down in decimal places changes the VALUE:

```
2.98789
2.9878
2.987
..
2.
```

When "2" gets assigned to the TB, the starting value for going up is 2.  you lost the rest of the decimals.   You need to store in a decimal variable and format THAT to go up and down as you want:

```
Dim decVal As Decimal = 2.987899 

Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
             ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged

    ' now, I am not changing the underlying VALUE, just the format
    TB1.Text = FormatNumber(decVal, NumericUpDown1.Value)
End Sub
```

I'm not sure how you get different results with `Math.Round` because the code shown will still **assign** a new **value** to the TB with fewer decimals and therefore lost.